# ImageMagick sepia effect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to process my images. How can I add sepia effect to my image using ImageMagick? I found that it is possible ([link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sepia-tone)), but I haven't found any info about how to do it.

I'm coding with Objective-C.

Comment: why don't you use the `CIFilter` of the `CoreImage.framework`...?

Comment: Well, I'm using ImageMagick for all my images processing (loading, saving, effects adjustment) so I don't know if starting to use CoreImage for only sepia would be good idea. I should add there pretty much code I guess for later image processing then.

Answer (score 0):

On the commandline it works like this:

```
convert image.jpeg -sepia-tone 80% sepia.png    # input: JPEG, output: PNG
convert image.jpeg -sepia-tone 90% sepia.tiff   # input: JPEG, output: TIFF, less sepia
convert image.jpeg -sepia-tone 70% sepia.tiff   # input: JPEG, output: TIFF, more sepia
convert image.png  -sepia-tone 60% sepia.png    # input: PNG, output: PNG, even more sepia
```

Easy, isn't it. Just experiment a bit to determine just *how much* (or how little) sepia you want.